# Android InputStream reads garbage ServerSocket running in a Thread. How should ServerSocket read from client socket?

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I have a an application which communicates between two android devices through socket. It seems like they do connect, but when data from the client socket is read by ServerSocket (using InputStream), it doesnot return the desired result (it is supposed to return somrthing like "21.24891706//95.23659845//ff8iuj67898n47fu" ).Instead I'm getting " [B@416b9488" as the message.

My client runs an **AsyncTask** and server runs a **Thread**.

Can you please help me solve this problem? Any help will is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

### Here is Server.java which runs on the server:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Server {
    Context context;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    String message = "";
    static final int socketServerPORT = 8080;
    ShowConnectedStudents activity;

    public Server(ShowConnectedStudents callingActivity) {
        activity = callingActivity;
        Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
        socketServerThread.start();
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return socketServerPORT;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

        int count = 0;
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        String message;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // create ServerSocket using specified port
                serverSocket=new ServerSocket();
                serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(socketServerPORT));

                while (true) {
                    // block the call until connection is created and return
                    // Socket object
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    message = "";

                    InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream br= new BufferedInputStream(input);
                    while ((bytesRead = br.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
                        message += " " + buffer.toString();
                    }
                    message += socket.isConnected();
                    message+=":"+socket.isClosed();
                    input.close();
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                activity.status.setText("Message is: " + message);
                        }
                    });

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Here is Client.java which runs on the client:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    String status = "";
    double Lat,Long;
    String deviceId;
    Socket socket = null;
    ConnectToDevice activity;
    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;

    Client(String addr, int port,double latitude,double longitude,String deviceIdentification,ConnectToDevice callingActivity) {
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
        Lat=latitude;
        Long=longitude;
        deviceId=deviceIdentification;
        activity=callingActivity;
        if(dstAddress.charAt(0)=='/'){
            dstAddress=dstAddress.substring(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        while(socket==null){
            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream,true);
            printStream.print(Lat + "//" + Long+"//"+deviceId);
            printStream.flush();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            status = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            status = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        } finally {

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        activity.statusText.setText(Lat+ "//" + Long+"//"+deviceId);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: `I'm getting " [B@416b9488"`. That is the java identifier string of your byte buffer. Not the contents of it. You probably wanted to convert the contents to sting and used buffer.toString(). But that is not the way itt should be done.

Comment: NB  `ServerSocket` doesn't read anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

toString() on a byte[] is not what you want, you're getting basically the memory address of the byte array

instead convert to a string, something like this

```
while ((bytesRead = br.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
    message += " " + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out another way, before reading this accepted answer. I'm posting it in case if it benefit anyone.

My data is text-only. So I wrapped the socket's input stream inside a Scanner.

```
InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
Scanner scanner= new Scanner(input);
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    message+=scanner.nextLine();
}
```